# What's the easiest way to scrape a Wikipedia table into a graph?

Tags: graphics, screen-scraping

What's the easiest way to quickly take a column like [these marathon times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon_world_record_progression#Marathon_world_record_progression) and display them as a graph?  Just an ad-hoc momentary view is sufficient; fancy formatting, editing, or saving as a file type isn't a concern.

Comment: The canonical answer is to take a screen capture of the table, print it out onto paper, place the paper in a wooden table (VERY important), take a picture of the paper, then run the picture through an OCR program.

Comment: How about get the data into an array then use [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)? But I like @MarcB's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- drag-select the table contents
- copy
- open Excel 97
- click Edit, Paste special..., Text
- select first through last cells in column A
- click Chart Wizard icon
- click Finish (for default chart; axis labels need work)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Selecting, copying, and pasting into Open office's calc worked for me. Formatting is a bit weird, but that's easily fixable.